# Haar measure on transversals

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

It is well known that there exists an invariant Haar measure on Locally compact group $G$. Haar measure on coset space and double coset space with respect to a closed subgroup $H$ and a compact subgroup $K$ is defined in  "A.Weil, L'integration dans les groupes topologiques et ses applications, Paris, 1938" and http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S1446788700028524 respectively.

Using these concepts, can we define Haar measure on the transversals (representatives of cosets)? that is, can the theory be made independent of subgroups?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Haar measure is defined specifically for groups. Of course, one can lift the measure from the quotient to a measure on any transversal, but in what sense would it be Haar? I also do not understand the meaning of "can the theory be made independent of subgroups". Can you clarify?

Comment: @studiosus Right transversals are algebraically right quasigroup. In that sense I wrote "can the theory be made independent of subgroups"

Comment: Aha, I am beginning to understand the question. Maybe you mean to define a generalization of Haar measure for (say) locally compact (this, of course would fail for arbitrary transversals) topological quasigroups? What axioms would you require? Binary operation preserves the measure?

Comment: @studiosus It should be Borel measure $m$ such that
$m(U) > 0$ for every non-empty Borel open set $U$ and $m(Ba) = m(B)$ for every Borel set $B$ and every $a \in S$, where $S$ is right quasiroup.

Comment: Did you try to google "Haar measure on a quasigroup"? You will get a fair number of references.