# Generalization of Haar measure to quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, measure-theory, haar-measure

Given a **not necessarily normal** subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, is it possible to define some short of generalized Haar measure on the quotient $G/H$?

In particular it should agree with the usual Haar measure in the case of $H$ normal.

Comment: You want $H$ to be closed. Then see the reference in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496128/haar-measure-on-transversals?rq=1

Comment: Also, most likely, it is covered in Bourbaki's chapter on Haar measures (in “Elements of mathematics. Integration”).